# No module named 'pandas' - Jupyter, Python3 Kernel, TensorFlow through Docker

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, docker-toolbox

I have a Docker container running from tensrflow with Jupyter (Python 3 Kernel) image: erroneousboat/tensorflow-python3-jupyter

This works great and I can access the jupyter notebook from

`http://DOCKER_IP:8888`

My only issue is that pandas library is not installed. So, I tried to install it on my own. I opened up the docker quickstart terminal and ran:

```
docker exec CONTAINER_ID apt-get update
docker exec CONTAINER_ID apt-get install -y python3-pandas
```

The installation succeeds, and yet I still get the ImportError: No module named 'pandas' when I try to import pandas in the jupyter notebook, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I also tried installing pandas to the image rather than just my container by:

```
docker run -it erroneousboat/tensorflow-python3-jupyter /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3-pandas
exit
```

Still, in my jupyter notebook, pandas is not recognized. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `pip install pandas`?

Comment: I have not. Just did and it worked! If you make this into an answer, I'll select it - thanks! Also, is there a reason why pip install would work and a system-wide install would not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install pandas` will install the latest version of pandas for you.

Based on your tags `python-3.x`, I assumed `pip` belongs to your Python3 version, if you have multiple python versions installed, make sure you have the correct pip.

Comment: It's weird that anaconda told me this was already installed but using `pip install pandas` fixed the problem in jupyter notebook